# dm_exec_connections does not show some connections

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Im trying to query dmvs to check if connections are encrypted. Using below query. The issue is some connections info are not getting returned by the query.

SQL 2016

Application name : EntityFramework

When i put a trace i can see user activity. 
But the query doesn't return info on that particular user but returns info on other SPIDs.

```
 SELECT   
    c.session_id, c.net_transport, c.encrypt_option,   
    c.auth_scheme, s.host_name, s.program_name,    
    s.client_interface_name, s.login_name, s.nt_domain, DB_NAME(s.database_id) AS dbname, 
    s.nt_user_name, s.original_login_name, c.connect_time,   
    s.login_time   
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS c  
JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s  
    ON c.session_id = s.session_id
```

Tried running the query multiple times with GO 25.
Looked online to see if any events on the trace or extended event could give info on if the session is encrypted but no luck.

Comment: Are you running this as sysadmin? You need VIEW SERVER STATE to see all sessions. See if there is a difference with LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

Comment: Yes, running as sysadmin. Tried Join change too, didnt work. the connection duration on the trace was less than a sec. So, i had user run a long query and got the output from the DMVs. Still, this doesnt explain it but worked this time.